# Alert the value in java-script which is queried from Database without using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, alert

i am working on a mini project to display value queried from database based on the check box selected.
i have come across many post : it can be done using ajax/jquery.
i donot know how to use ajax.
pl help me i am stuck at final Alert window output.

Here is my main test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>--</title>

<script>    

function checkAddress()
{


    if (document.querySelector('form[name="frmUser"] input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) {
        //alert("Success! (form would be submitted here)");
        var $temp = <?php include 'alert.php';?>
        //alert("Success! (form would be submitted here)");
        alert($temp)
        document.frmUser.action = "test.php";
        document.frmUser.submit();
    } else {
        alert("Pl select checkbox which You wish to Update ");
    }
}


</script>

</head>

<body >

<h1 style="text-align:center;"></h1>
<?php

// php populate html table from mysql database

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","11111111");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "test");
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM inputs ORDER BY userId DESC");
?>

<div class="form-style-1">
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div style="width:1200px;">
<table style="text-align:center;"border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="1200" class="tblListForm" align="center">
<tr class="listheader">
<td></td>
<td>SN</td>
<th>Domain</th>
<th>department</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
$j=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($i%2==0){
$classname="evenRow";
} else {
 $classname="oddRow";
}
?>
<tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) {
 echo $classname; 
 }?>">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["userId"]; ?>" ></td>
<td><?php echo $row["userId"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["department"]; ?></td>

<th colspan="4"><input type="button" name="update" class="button" value="Apply" onClick="checkAddress(this);" /></th></tr>
<?php 
$i++;
$j=$i+1;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
</div>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my alert.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "11111111";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$rowCount = count($_POST['users']);
//echo "The rowcount is ".$rowCount.""; 
 $queried_name;
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
$num_var= " ";
$num_var = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['users'][$i]);
//echo "The numvar is ".$num_var.""; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM inputs WHERE userId='".$num_var."'");
if (!$result) {
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
        exit;
    }

while($row[$i]= mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {

$queried_name = $row[$i]['department']; 
return $queried_name;
echo 'alert("Please Use below department.' .$queried_name.'")';
}}}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You either have to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) or have an inline javascript tag with php echo in it (not pretty).

Comment: i tried using the below code also `
if (document.querySelector('form[name="frmUser"]`
 `input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) {`
       ` //alert("Success! (form would be submitted here)");`
        `var $temp = <?php Function Query()';?>`
        
        `alert($temp)`
        `document.frmUser.action = "test.php";`
        `document.frmUser.submit();`

` and created a function named Function Query() in same php file with additional code as `return $queried_name;`

Comment: pl help me with the ajax code . i have no idea how to use here.

Comment: You could also have an if/else on your page for when `$_POST['submit']` is present and when it isn't and then divide the functionality ([sample](https://pastebin.com/YdapHunQ)). Without a more specific question, it is hard for me to be more specific in the answer.

Comment: the alert windows shows as  Undefined. i have used `$_POST['submit']` in my alert.php file because post in self page is not working in my case. Everything is working fine , i am able to get the values from database and spass it to my main php file under `function checkAddress()`. but only thing is i am not able to display value

Comment: Sir, you are including php files inside your `script` tags, I am not sure why you don't see how it fails. Please tell me what it is that you are trying to achieve. The only possible way to help you that I see is by going through the code from scratch.

Comment: Sorry for the whole script. i want to display value from database based on the checkbox selected. once the checkbox is selected, on submitting the form, the value is queried from database and should be displayed in a Alert Window

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense. Are you allowed to use jQuery for this project? Do you have experience with it? This determines how the function is going to look like. Do you need to output an `alert` specifically or would you be alright with displaying output on the same page? Do you have a separate php file that produces the output? What is it called? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can make use of their inbuilt [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. If you are limited to "vanilla" javascript, below is the function I normally use for AJAX calls:

```
function ajaxQuery(url, method, param, async, onsuccess, onfailure) {
    var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var callback = function(r) { r.status==200 ? (typeof(onsuccess)=='function' && onsuccess(r)) : (typeof(onfailure)=='function' && onfailure(r)); };

    if(async) { xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4) { callback(xmlHttpRequest); } } }
    xmlHttpRequest.open(method, url, async);
    xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('X-REQUESTED-WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    if(method == 'POST') { xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); }
    xmlHttpRequest.send(param);
    if(!async) { callback(xmlHttpRequest); }
}
```

Usage example:

```
ajaxQuery('alert.php', 'GET', null, true, function(r) {
    alert(r.responseText);
}, function() { alert('Something went wrong.'); });
```

Naturally, if `alert.php` performs any complex tasks, it will have to take parameters, and you then could refer to `alert.php?parameter0=something&parameter1=something` instead of just `alert.php`.

I would recommend doing something a bit more simple at this stage, as you are confusing php with javascript, and you seem to not quite understand what exactly an `include` statement does in a php file. It doesn't return the output of the script - what it does is kind of equivalent to echoing *the whole php file* into another! You were assigning the contents of `alert.php` to poor old `alert()` from javascript. I would personally separate out the projects into languages at this stage (do something purely in javascript, purely in php, etc.) and start mixing them together when I felt ready.

You don't need javascript to assign a value to a form's `action` attribute. This can be done inside the `form` tag itself.

Please let me know if anything needs to be explained further.

---

**Update**: here are the code samples you have requested. I went through your code and "fixed" it. Important notes: you should pick a formatting standard and *stick to it*. Examples:

- You connect to the database in 2 different places in 2 different ways, you should have a single database connection file that you include in all the relevant php's.
- Your quotation marks are sometimes single and sometimes - double, I personally only use double quotes when necessary or convenient (SQL queries, strings containing special characters like `"\n"`).
- Indentation wasn't following any particular logic, and empty lines were everywhere; it's important that you format your code so that you and others can read it in a few months when no-one remembers what the hell it was about.
- In your test.php you have a table nested inside a div, nested inside a form, nested inside a div - that's hardly necessary.
- Why are there empty `td` and `th` tags present?
- You should pay close attention to how your HTML tags are closed: I've noticed a few `" >` and `" />`. Of course, browsers won't care for the most part, but your code readability suffers.
- HTML attributes are always lowercase, as far as I know (`onClick` should be `onclick`, etc.).
- Your table layout is strange, but I didn't touch it. I have no idea why you have a `colspan="4"` element in every row.
- Method names (`GET` and `POST`) should always be uppercase (except in XHTML where it's the other way around).

1) test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>--</title>
    <script>
    function ajaxQuery(url, method, param, async, onsuccess, onfailure) {
        var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var callback = function(r) { r.status==200 ? (typeof(onsuccess)=='function' && onsuccess(r)) : (typeof(onfailure)=='function' && onfailure(r)); };
        if(async) { xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState==4) { callback(xmlHttpRequest); } } }
        xmlHttpRequest.open(method, url, async);
        xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('X-REQUESTED-WITH', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        if(method == 'POST') { xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); }
        xmlHttpRequest.send(param);
        if(!async) { callback(xmlHttpRequest); }
    }

    function checkAddress(e) {
        var checkbox = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');
        if(checkbox) {
            ajaxQuery('alert.php', 'POST', 'users[]='+checkbox.value, true, function(request) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }, function() { alert('Shiver me timbers!'); });
        } else {
            alert('Please select a checkbox to update.');
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;"></h1>
    <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '11111111');
        mysqli_select_db($conn, 'test');
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM inputs ORDER BY userId DESC");
    ?>
    <div class="form-style-1">
        <form name="frmUser" method="POST" action="test.php">
            <div style="width: 1200px;">
                <table style="text-align: center;" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="1200" class="tblListForm" align="center">
                    <tr class="listheader">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>SN</td>
                        <th>Domain</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $i=0;
                    $j=1;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $classname = $i%2==0 ? 'evenRow' : 'oddRow';
                    ?>
                    <tr<?php if(isset($classname)) { echo ' class="'.$classname.'"'; } ?>>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?=$row["userId"];?>">
                        </td>
                        <td><?=$row["userId"];?></td>
                        <td><?=$row["department"];?></td>
                        <th colspan="4">
                            <input type="button" name="update" class="button" value="Apply" onclick="javascript: checkAddress(event);">
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                        $i++;
                        $j=$i+1;
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2) alert.php

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '11111111';
$dbname = 'test';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); // Create connection
if($conn->connect_error) { die('Connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error); } // Check connection
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $rowCount = count($_POST['users']);
    $num_var= '';
    $queried_name = '';
    for($i=0; $i<$rowCount; $i++) {
        $num_var = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['users'][$i]);
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM inputs WHERE userId='".$num_var."'");
        if(!$result) { die('MySQL Error: '.mysqli_error($conn)); }
        while($row[$i]= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $queried_name = $row[$i]['department'];
            echo "Please refer to the following department: $queried_name\n";
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pyromonk. you have helped in increasing my knowledge on ajax, javascript and php

Comment: @Prayag, I am glad I was able to help. It's very important to tackle those things one step at a time. I found those same things confusing when I just started out, it's important to not despair and to give yourself some room, because things can and will be overwhelming, but they will eventually get easier. Don't give up! A lot of people out there don't even have the courage to build a project you try to build and simply brush off the idea of anything more complex than Excel.

Comment: pl if possible help me with a sample code in which : if any one of checkbox is selected ; after submit , the value of that checkbox (in my case Department) is being populated through an alert window. you help is appreciated. i am not well experience with Ajax.

Comment: by using any code, i will later on try to understand that code step by step.

Comment: @Prayag, what do you mean by "populated through an alert window"?

Comment: the value is being displayed through Alert window.

Comment: @Prayag. do you want to display the value of the checkbox or the output of alert.php?

Comment: my main Motive is  to display the value based on checkbox in the alert window. for e.g in my case if i have selected checkbox id 1 , then alert window should say "Please Use **IT** department.". since i have stored IT value under id=1 in database.

Comment: by using my code, nothing is displayed only just my url is changed from `localhost/test.php` to `localhost/test.php?users%5B%5D=3` because i had selected checkbox 3

Comment: It's late where I live, I will go through your code and update my answer tomorrow if you don't mind.

Comment: No issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: @Prayag, I have updated my answer with a more detailed analysis of your code and the rewritten version thereof. If you do indeed read through and learn from it like you've promised, you should be able to adjust anything I might've overlooked because of not being completely aware of your goal.

Comment: i appreciate the work you have done for providing the code. my code also contains some CSS script, not included in my post hence th tr is used for ancy look of the table, i

Comment: @Prayag, thank you, I could see that from the code. But 4 nested block elements is usually a sign of css having gone haywire. Hopefully, my analysis will help you.

Comment: i appreciate the work you have done for providing the code. my code also contains some CSS script, not included in my post hence th tr is used for ancy look of the table.

i am getting error as  `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`. i changed it to ` javascript: checkAddress(event);` .

     i am getting a blank alert box [link]https://ibb.co/nDqsBQ [link]

Comment: once again thanks for your support. i am not able to figure it out right now bcoz lack of knowdledge. i wll learn try and will improvise myself.

Comment: @Prayag, What does alert.php return when run by itself? If it returns nothing, then the alert will also return nothing. I have absolutely no information about your database structure, so I haven't touched the logical part of the loops that gather database information. As for the reference error, I have mixed up `e` and `event`, I apologise, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Prayag, try substituting both occurences of `$row[$i]` with `$row` in your alert.php. That's another thing I overlooked.

Comment: still i am getting `test.php:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined` as per your ne updated code. if i Change the `e to event in checkAddress(event) ` then alert window blank is observed also i am not getting error `Please select a checkbox to update.` if none are selected.

Comment: @Prayag, I've tested the javascript bit of the code on my end, are you sure yours has been copied properly? There were 2 instances of `event` in the function initially and 1 instance of `e` inside `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

First, `alert('something');` is a JavaScript sentences. It must be written inside `<script>alert(0)</script>` tag or some attributes like `onclick="alert(0)"`,so that the browser can excute it.

Second, AJAX is a technology which also be written in JavaScript. You must make sure the `url` AJAX requesting to can return data as response. The simplest php file the AJAX requesting to may like this `<?php echo 'hello world.'?>`.So, when the AJAX request send to the php file url, you will get a response data 'hello world.' Here is a useful website for AJAX learning. [MDN/AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)